# "File has stopped working" when using BGI?

Tags: c, bgi

I am using code blocks as my default IDE to code my c programs. but I am constantly getting the error that file has stopped working whenever I compile the following code related to graphics in c programming.

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
int gd=0,gm;
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");
circle(300,200,80);
getch();
closegraph();
}
```

I am getting no error and no warning. But still I am unable to run this code properly. I have added all the files like library and header files in correct order. Please help me to run this code successfully.

Comment: Is it Borland C in disguise?

Comment: @HaymantMangla TurboC accessed the graphics card directly. That can't be done on a modern PC, you'll have to run this in a simulator.

Comment: Yep... "_*graphmode is an integer that specifies the initial graphics mode (unless *graphdriver equals DETECT; in which case, *graphmode is set by initgraph to the highest resolution available for the detected driver)._" (`DETECT` is `0`).

Comment: I suddenly feel afraid that I'm going to wake up and discover that the past 25 years were all a dream.

Comment: Assuming you are running on a system such as MS-DOS 6.22 you need the BGI files to be available.

Comment: @Attie the code sample in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Graphics_Interface) shows that the OP's program is correct. The second argument is the return value from the function, although properly the first argument should be passed from `int gd = DETECT`.

Comment: @JoeFarrell in some countries the dream is to one day being able to afford modern technology. The Linux OS and the gcc compiler are free, but the computers they run on are not. In such places everything is recycled. If a bright spark has an opportunity to learn on an ancient machine, let's not discourage that.

Comment: It was meant as a joke, just because I haven't seen `graphics.h` in so very long. My apologies if anyone took offense.

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  and `int main( void )`